# How do I return the result (an array) of a function once for each button click rather than continuously pushing to another array?

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I have is that on every button click, the result of my function, which is an array pushes continuously to a primary array. The most important elements in my HTML page are:

1. Two input element of the type:number with ids of `#firstinput` and
   `#secondinput`;
2. A button with id `#submit`;
3. A div to show result with id `#result`.

I had an idea of refreshing my browser on every click with the use of `window.location.reload()`, but this does not solve the problem as the result of my work will disappear instantly.

Here is my **JavaScript** Code:

```
let scale = [],
submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", weightBalancer);

function weightBalancer() {
    let weightsForLeftAndRightSides = document.querySelector("#firstinput").value,
        weightsForBalancing = document.querySelector("#secondinput").value;
    inputValidator(weightsForLeftAndRightSides, weightsForBalancing);
    inputValuesToJson(weightsForLeftAndRightSides, weightsForBalancing);
}

function inputValidator(firstInput, SecondInput) {
    if (firstInput == "" || SecondInput == ""
        || isNaN(firstInput) || isNaN(SecondInput)) {
        return alert("Enter the require number of digits");
    }
    if (firstInput < 10 || SecondInput > 99) {
        return alert("Enter the require number of digits");
    }
    if (firstInput < 1000 || SecondInput > 9999) {
        return alert("Enter the require number of digits");
    }
}

function inputValuesToJson(firstInput, secondinput) {
    let firstInputArray = Array.from(firstInput.toString()).map(Number),
        secondInputArray = Array.from(secondinput.toString()).map(Number);

    scale.push(JSON.stringify(firstInputArray));
    scale.push(JSON.stringify(secondInputArray));
    //I will remove this later
    console.log(scale);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = firstInput;
}
```

I expect to the function to return:

1. nothing instead of `["[]","[]"]` if input elements are empty on
   button click;
2. e.g. `["[]","[]"] and ["[1,2]","[1,4,2,3]"]` on two separate button clicks respectively instead of `["[]","[]","[1,2]","[1,4,2,3]"]` on the second click.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you use let scale?

Comment: Move the `let scale = []` part that creates the array inside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a hard time understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish but how about doing this instead of pushing to a global variable

```
function inputValuesToJson(firstInput, secondinput) {
    let firstInputArray = Array.from(firstInput.toString()).map(Number),
        secondInputArray = Array.from(secondinput.toString()).map(Number);

    // scale.push(JSON.stringify(firstInputArray));
    // scale.push(JSON.stringify(secondInputArray));
    // I will remove this later
    const myArray = [ ...JSON.stringify(firstInputArray), ...JSON.stringify(secondInputArray) ]
    console.log(myArray);

    // return myArray & consume it wherever you want. The array will be reset 
    // at every call to this function and therefor you will have the expected 
    // result 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = firstInput;
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use spread syntax here, especially not on two strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. nothing instead of ["[]","[]"] if input elements are empty on button click; 
   To Achieve this, all you need to do is run a null check inside your inputValuesToJson function. Add your entire block into a simple if condition.

   if (firstInput, secondinput)
   {
   your content goes here... }
2. e.g. ["[ ]","[ ]"] and ["[1,2]","[1,4,2,3]"] on two separate button clicks respectively instead of ["[ ]","[ ]","[1,2]","[1,4,2,3]"] on the second click.

You want your array to capture each event click separately, create an array property in the function which is called each time the click event is triggered. Try moving the let scale = [ ] inside your inputValuesToJson() function.